# How to update primary key value in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have table(and also entity in Entity Data Model) `Person` with following fields:

```
Name              Type
SocialID          String      
FirstName         String
LastName          String
```

which `SocialID` is Primary Key. I want to update value of `SocialID` for each record. However when i try to update this field in Entity Framework I get following error:

```
The property 'SocialID' is part of the object's key information and cannot 
be modified.
```

The code that i get above error is:

```
foreach (var p in Entity.Persons)
{
   p.SocialID= p.SocialID + "00";
   Entity.SaveChanges();
}
```

How I can do this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by the others, you can't do it in code. You will have to make your update in SQL. Either in a migration or directly in SQL Server Management Studio (or the equivalent if you're using a different database).

```
UPDATE Person -- Or 'Persons' if that's what your table is called
SET SocialID = SocialID + '00'
```

It will require a lot more work than this if you have other tables use this column as a foreign key (you'll have to drop the constraints first -- on all tables that reference your primary key -- then fix the data and recreate the constraints). Or as Moe said in the comments, you can set your foreign keys to cascade on update.

Comment: yes i have another table that have reference to this table. thank you, but i need change this programmatically in C# and Entity framework!

Comment: You can change your foreign key to cascade on update, that should make it easier.  The other option is to drop the foreign key, update table A then table B and then re-create the foreign key.

Comment: Why do you have to do it programmatically. Primary keys are not really supposed to change at all (even though there's sometimes a need to make a one-off change to them). Doing it in code suggests you're doing it more than once, which is probably wrong and maybe the column you're updating shouldn't be the key.

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge primary key once generated cant be updated programatically,that defies the purpose of primary key.
It'll be better if you insert all your data again with new primary keys and delete old data.

Comment: Wow! I need previews data!

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want to change the primary key? Entity framework will be using that field to identify the object, you can't change its value while it is the primary key.

Based on the first answer I suggest you change the table Person to have its own primary key, let's say PersonID and mantain the SocialID as a foreign key to the Social table. If you need a person to have several Social records you may need to create other table to correspond the PersonId to several SocialId, removing the SocialId from the person table.

Comment: Because of changing Social style

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi In that case you are not talking about a primary key but a foreign key. You should add a new key to that table identifing the person. SocialId should be the primary key of the Social style table.

Comment: If you want to update primary key for all record in table - use database script. Entity Framework don't permit changing of primary key.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov based on his comment I don't think he wants to do that.

Comment: I am afraid that SocialId is natural key (and there is no foreign key) and format of this key was changed.